# End-to-end property

Tags: networking, system, distributed-computing

I understand the end-to-end principle from the classic MIT paper, which states that executing a function between 2 remote nodes does not depend on the states of the in-between nodes.

But what is end-to-end encryption, end-to-end guarantees, end-to-end protocols, etc...? I couldn't find a precise definition of end-to-end. The term seems to be over-used.

In other words, when one describes a system property X as end-to-end, what does it mean? What is the opposite of end-to-end?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think end-to-end is over-used. It merely says that the property holds from one end to the other. An "end" can be a node or a layer in the computing stack.

Consider three nodes: A, B and C. Node A wants to talk with C. B sits between A and C and forwards messages between them. B is, for example, a load balancer or a gateway.

Encryption is end-to-end if B cannot read and tamper messages sent from A to C. A concrete example is the following: A is your laptop, C is a remote machine in your network at home or work. B is a VPN gateway. The encryption here is **not** end-to-end because only the link between A and B is actually encrypted. An attacker sitting between B and C would be able to read the clear text. That might be fine in practice, but it is not end-to-end.

Another example. Say we don't care about encryption, but about reliable message transmission. You know that the network might corrupt bits of messages. Therefore, TCP and other protocols have a checksum field that is checked whenever messages are received. But the guarantees of these checksums is not necessarily end-to-end.

If A sends a message *m* to C relying on the TCP's checksum, a node B sitting in the middle could corrupt the message in an undetectable way. Abstracting most details, node B basically (1) receives *m*, (2) checks *m*'s checksum, (3) finds the route to C and creates a new message with *m*'s payload, (4) calculates a new checksum for *m*, and (5) sends *m* (with the new checksum) to C. Now, if node B corrupts the message after (2) but before step (4), the resulting message arriving on C is corrupted but that cannot be detected by looking at *m*'s checksum! Therefore, such checksum is not end-to-end. Node B does not even have to be malicious. Such a corruption can be caused by hardware errors or more probably by bugs in node B. This has happened a couple of times in Amazon S3 service, for example: [this case](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=22709) and [this case](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=86214) and [this case](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=262676).

The solution is, obviously, to use application-level checksums, which are end-to-end. Here, a checksum of *m*'s payload is appended to the payload before calculating the lower layer checksum.